# sed command to comment out specific block of code containing search string

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a `listener.ora` file for Oracle in which I need to comment out a block of lines specified by a search string, e.g.,

```
>(DESCRIPTION=
>>(ADDRESS_LIST=
>>>(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sale-server)(PORT=1521))
>>>(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))))
>SID_LIST_LISTENER=
>>(SID_LIST=
>>>(SID_DESC=
>>>>(GLOBAL_DBNAME=sales)
>>>>(ORACLE_HOME=/oracle9i)
>>>>(SID_NAME=ales)
>>>>(PROGRAM=extproc))
>>>(SID_DESC=
>>>>(SID_NAME=plsextproc)
>>>>(ORACLE_HOME=/oracle9i)
>>>>(PROGRAM=extproc)))
```

In the above file I have to search for `sales` (which is db name) and comment out the whole block which contains that string until the next `SID_DESC` block. e.g., Desired output:

```
>(DESCRIPTION=  
>>(ADDRESS_LIST=  
>>>(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sale-server)(PORT=1521))  
>>>(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))))  
>SID_LIST_LISTENER=  
>>(SID_LIST=  
>>>#(SID_DESC=  
>>>>#(GLOBAL_DBNAME=sales)  
>>>>#(ORACLE_HOME=/oracle9i)  
>>>>#(SID_NAME=ales)  
>>>>#(PROGRAM=extproc))  
>>>(SID_DESC=  
>>>>(SID_NAME=plsextproc)  
>>>>(ORACLE_HOME=/oracle9i)  
>>>>(PROGRAM=extproc)))
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: user138725: Seriously, tell us what you want the output to be.  Not a hand-wavy *description* of it (I don’t know what you mean by “comment”); tell us what you want the output to ***be***.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And please describe *what* you want to do more explicitly.  I get that you want to do something (unclear) to a “block” that begins with `SID_DESC` and contains `sales`.  What defines the end of a block?  A line containing `(PROGRAM=extproc)` or some portion of that?  A line ending with `))`?  Everything up to the next line containing `SID_DESC`?  What if the block containing `sales` is the last one in the file, so there is no next line?  And, if the block containing `sales` is the last one in the file, what do you want done with the `)))` at the end of the `PROGRAM=extproc` line?

Comment: Here I want to disable a block of content by searching a database name "sales" inside that block only.There could be many blocks for different databases. For a block of content for any specific database:

Comment: Here I want to disable a block of content by searching a database name "sales" inside that block only.There could be many blocks for different databases. For a block of content for any specific database:
1. database name could be anywhere inside that SID_DESC block covered by ()
2. other blocks shouldn't be commented(by adding # in begining)
3. A SID_DESC block may have many lines until the next SID_DESC block.

so basically, the sed will search for database name and will comment lines before till it finds SID_DESC and after until it finds next SID_DESC line. 

I hope this explains my problem.

Comment: The lines in block letters should be commented with # to disable the block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like this is not a job for a single sed command but for a complete shell script.

1. Define a line counter
2. Define SID markers
3. Read line by line
4. Mark each SID location (put them in an array)
5. Mark each pattern match location (put them in another array)
6. Check arrays. If the match is between SIDs, comment all lines from first SID to second SID - 1 line

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simple task for `sed`

```
sed '
    /SID_DESC/{
        /\n/{
            P
            D
            }
        :1
        N
        /PROGRAM/!b1
        /sales/s/[^\n]*\n/#&/g
        }
    ' listener.ora
```

Comment: I have flagged the question as unclear and commented on it.  But, given that the OP says, "I need to *comment* specific block of lines" (emphasis added), and your solution *deletes* a block of lines, I suspect that this is not what the question is asking for.

Comment: @G-Man it is easy to exchange `/sales/d` for delete by `/sales/s/^/#/gm` for comment

Comment: OK, but note that the `m` option to the `s` command is a GNU extension (not POSIX-compliant).

Comment: @G-Man If you so worry re POSIX-compilant you can use `/sales/s/^\|\n/&#/g`

Comment: Here I want to disable a block of content by searching a database name "sales" inside that block only.There could be many blocks for different databases. For a block of content for any specific database:
1. database name could be anywhere inside that SID_DESC block covered by ()
2. other blocks shouldn't be commented(by adding # in begining)
3. A SID_DESC block may have many lines until the next SID_DESC block.

so basically, the sed will search for database name and will comment lines before till it finds SID_DESC and after until it finds next SID_DESC line. 

I hope this explains my problem.

Comment: The lines in block letters should be commented with # to disable the block of code. Please find the desired output in my question.

Comment: @user138725 I have modified the script. Please check